# proper logging module sanitizing on fork (multiprocessing module)

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, locking

I have a problem when using 'logging' module together with 'multiprocessing' module. The forked child ends up with a lock and hangs up on any log attempt.

The logger is using StreamHandler for sys.stdout and sys.stderr and SysLogHandler (which apparently carries active lock from its parent).

The scheme is as follows:

- workers are implemented as threads (Thread)
- jobs executed by workers are sub-processes (Process)

I keep getting locks in various places as: logging._lock, SysLogHandler.lock, depending on my attempts to sanitize the module.

In general I do not like to interact with modules beyond their API, but in this case I boldly tried:

```
cur_logger = logging.getLogger()
cur_logger.handlers = []
logging._lock = RLock()
logging._handlerList = []
logging._handlers = {}
logging.Logger.manager.loggingDict = {}
```

With the following result (still lock):

```
#0  0x00007fc87bceba00 in sem_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fc87bff8428 in PyThread_acquire_lock (lock=0x921970, waitflag=1) at Python/thread_pthread.h:349
#2  0x00007fc87bffc314 in lock_PyThread_acquire_lock (self=0x7fc87c3ce120, args=<value optimized out>) at Modules/threadmodule.c:47
#3  0x00007fc87bfd09d4 in call_function (f=<value optimized out>, throwflag=<value optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3794
#4  PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<value optimized out>, throwflag=<value optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:2453
#5  0x00007fc87bfd2647 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7fc87c3f1828, globals=<value optimized out>, locals=<value optimized out>, args=<value optimized out>, argcount=1, kws=0x7fc85c003fd0, kwcount=0, defs=0x7fc87c3666e8, defcount=1, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3044
```

I use quite old packages, so my question is whether it is a known bug fixed later, or there is a way to sanitize somehow the logging module on fork, so that it will clear all locks (AFAIK these are not system locks and they are irrelevant after fork), or maybe I am doing something the wrong way.

Thanks,

Versions:

- python: python-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64
- logging.**version**: 0.5.0.5
- multiprocessing.**version**: 0.70a1

Edit_1:

I did the same test on CentOS 7, which has better debugger output for python, and it hangs due to SysLogHandler.lock (_RLock__count=1):

- should I focus on tracking SyLogHandler instance which was carried into a child
- or there is another logging suitable for 'multiprocessing'
- or the lock is somehow caused by my code

Debug:

```
#0  0x00007f4fa0e7b89c in __lll_lock_wait_private () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f4fa0e94fad in _L_lock_774 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f4fa0e94d65 in __check_pf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007f4fa0e56fd9 in getaddrinfo () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007f4f98b85c92 in setipaddr (name=<optimized out>, addr_ret=addr_ret@entry=0x7f4f82ff9cf0, addr_ret_size=addr_ret_size@entry=16, af=af@entry=2)
at /usr/src/debug/Python-2.7.5/Modules/socketmodule.c:921
#5  0x00007f4f98b8781e in getsockaddrarg (s=s@entry=0x7f4f896aadb0, args=<optimized out>, addr_ret=addr_ret@entry=0x7f4f82ff9cf0, len_ret=len_ret@entry=0x7f4f82ff9c80)
at /usr/src/debug/Python-2.7.5/Modules/socketmodule.c:1321
#6  0x00007f4f98b87c63 in sock_sendto (s=0x7f4f896aadb0, 
args=('<159>Jun 11 14:55:08 xdc.py.Distribute file as xdcrm.139979476948736: DEBUG [16722.139979476948736] _put:Timing SFTP stat+put of /tmp/blob.1M.bin.tmp to 10.67.145.141:/tmp/blob.1M.bin.tmp finished:True size:1048576 time:timer: 0.0349\x00', ('localhost', 514))) at /usr/src/debug/Python-2.7.5/Modules/socketmodule.c:2936
#7  0x00007f4fa1b45cf0 in call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7f4f82ff9ea0) at /usr/src/debug/Python-2.7.5/Python/ceval.c:4408
#8  PyEval_EvalFrameEx (
f=f@entry=Frame 0x7f4f824d5a00, for file /usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/handlers.py, line 863, in emit (self=<SysLogHandler(socket=<_socketobject at remote 0x7f4f8900e980>, level=0, lock=<_RLock(_Verbose__verbose=False, _RLock__owner=139979476948736, _RLock__block=<thread.lock at remote 0x7f4fa1fd4210>, _RLock__count=1) at remote 0x7f4f887bf2d0>,
```

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: use `QueueHandler` (child) and `QueueListener` (parent): https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#dealing-with-handlers-that-block

I observed the same problem using Python 3.5.2 and the (now) built-in multiprocessing and logging modules.

After some digging, it turns out this problem has been known for a while: https://bugs.python.org/issue6721

A fix for the Python locks was attempted in 3.7.4: https://bugs.python.org/issue36533. Immediately after testing the "fixed" version, I stumbled upon another deadlock, this time in the file i/o object. This one has a lock around flushing the data. The problem is essentially the same - the forked child process inherits an acquired lock with no means of releasing it. Except this one occurs in the C code, making it harder to debug :o

I ended up using a queue through the built-in queue logging helpers.